# Trying to remotely access through wmi using C#

Tags: c#, .net, wmi, remote-access

I have this piece of code:

```
private ManagementScope CreateNewManagementScope(string server)
    {
        string serverString = "\\\\" + server + "\\root\\cimv2";

        ConnectionOptions options = new ConnectionOptions();
        options.Username = "name";
        options.Password = "password";

        ManagementScope scope = new ManagementScope(serverString, options);
        scope.Connect();

        return scope;
    }
```

With that code I am trying to remotely access another PC though WMI. The password and the username are 100% correct (I tested them with wmic /node:pc /username:name /password:pwd and this worked) but I am getting access denied

> (Exception from  HRESULT: 0x80070005 (E_ACCESSDENIED))

Any Ideas what I am doing wrong? I am working with Win 7/C#/.NET 4.0
Thanks for any Help!

Comment: Are you on a domain or anything? You may have to specify your domain name in the Username, or if you are doing that you may not need to etc, also check your password for special characters which may not be escaped.

Comment: Well I tried domain\\user (double \\ because of escaping), but did not work. Password has just a dot but no other specials. I seriously do not understand why this does not work.

Comment: Does the account you're trying to access the other pc with got enough rights to connect? IE is it a network-administrator for example?

Comment: as the same user are you able to access an event log of the remote machine? I mean though Event Viewer.

Answer (score 0):

you can try with admin credential :

```
string serverString = @"\\" + strIPAddress + @"\root\cimv2"
```

Comment: Does not work .. tried this yet before when I was looking for helping articles .. thanks for the try :)

Answer (score 0):

Check what is logged on the other machines Security eventlog since it will provide you with a clue on what's wrong with access permissions.

I'm quite sure that you can solve the issue after checking the TechNet article ["Connecting to WMI Remotely Starting with Windows Vista"](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa822854) and the related one. Specifically this part: 
["Setting DCOM Security to Allow a User to Access a Computer Remotely"](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa393266#Setting_DCOM_Security_to_Allow_a_User_to_Access_a_Computer_Remotely).

Answer (score 0):

Check the code of [Services+](http://servicesplus.codeplex.com/) (Advanced Windows Service Manager) contains all what you need about WMI Win32_Service.

To Troubleshoot or debug:

1. Make sure the computer and server are on the same domain
2. Remove your code credential and make an EXE form your code then Run
   the EXE as privileged user.
3. Use [Services+](http://servicesplus.codeplex.com/) (mentioned above) or Services.msc to connect to the
   server.
4. Make sure RPC service is running on Remote Server.
5. Try to trun off the firewall temporary on the server.

Answer (score 0):

I was stucked with this same problem and what worked for me was:

1. First, you need to identify the Server that you want to monitor, then head to the Services.msc and ensure that the Remote Procedure Call and Remote Registry and Windows Management Instrumentation are running.
2. In the Windows start search space, enter wmimgmt.msc to open the WMI Console. Open it by heading to the right pane by clicking More Actions then Properties. In the prompt select the Security tab, select the Root folder then look for CIMV2, select it then click the Security tab below it. Add the user of the remote computer you will use its credentials by giving it all the permissions listed there, more so the Remote enable and Execute methods. Finish by clicking Ok.
3. In the remote computer open the CMD with administrator privileges and paste in this command: **sc sdset SCMANAGER D:(A;;CCLCRPRC;;;AU)(A;;CCLCRPWPRC;;;SY)(A;;KA;;;BA)S:(AU;FA;KA;;;WD)(AU;OIIOFA;GA;;;WD)**
4. Ensure that you are running Visual Studio as an administrator.

Hope it helps the next person!